# Programatically Configuring federatedAuthentication element in microsoft.identityModel on asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif

I am trying to programatically generate the following configuration contained inside the microsoft.identityModel configuration.

```
<federatedAuthentication>
   <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false" requireHttps="true" issuer="https://IssuedByFoo.com" realm="http://Foo.com/" />
   <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" path="/" />
</federatedAuthentication>
```

So far I have not been able to successfully configure this. I have tried setting the following in application_Start but I get an error message when I try to federate

"ID5002: The Issuer property on the FederatedPassiveSignIn control must be set to the address of an STS endpoint that can process WS-Federation passive protocol messages."

```
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Realm = "http://Foo.com/";
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer = "https://IssuedByFoo.com";
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.PassiveRedirectEnabled = false;
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RequireHttps = true;
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.RequireSsl = true;
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.Path = "/";
```

I am pretty sure that I am not configuring FederatedAuthentication correctly, and I am not sure where to configure it correctly. One thing I notice is that when I set a breakpoint on begin request, and inspect the FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule I do not see the properties set on it when the values are not present in the web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with this

[Is it possible to get ACS claims without editing web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473188/is-it-possible-to-get-acs-claims-without-editing-web-config)

This seems to work, and we were already usign a custom Module so it was easy to implement

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up post.  Extremely helpful link

Answer (score 10):

I always manage all my wif config from code, and just use app settings for the rp and sts server names etc.
This set up should work for you. btw - This is the set up for a relying party (the sts setup is simpler.)

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {

      FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated += FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated;

      }

       private static void FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated(object sender, FederationConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        //from appsettings...
        const string allowedAudience = "http://audience1/user/get";
        const string rpRealm = "http://audience1/";
        const string domain = "";
        const bool requireSsl = false;
        const string issuer = "http://sts/token/create";
        const string certThumbprint = "mythumbprint";
        const string authCookieName = "StsAuth";

        var federationConfiguration = new FederationConfiguration();
                                 federationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(allowedAudience));

        var issuingAuthority = new IssuingAuthority(internalSts);
        issuingAuthority.Thumbprints.Add(certThumbprint);
        issuingAuthority.Issuers.Add(internalSts);
        var issuingAuthorities = new List<IssuingAuthority> {issuingAuthority};

        var validatingIssuerNameRegistry = new ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry {IssuingAuthorities = issuingAuthorities};
        federationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = validatingIssuerNameRegistry;
        federationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

        var chunkedCookieHandler = new ChunkedCookieHandler {RequireSsl = false, Name = authCookieName, Domain = domain, PersistentSessionLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)};
        federationConfiguration.CookieHandler = chunkedCookieHandler;
        federationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer = issuer;
        federationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm = rpRealm;
        federationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.RequireHttps = requireSsl;

        e.FederationConfiguration = federationConfiguration;
```

Comment: What assemblies are needed and mus be included in the using, for this to work?

Comment: **References:** System.IdentityModel, System.IdentityModel.Services; **NuGet package:** System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry